# How much data can SQL Server handle without a DBA / other professionals?

Tags: sql-server, scalability

We deploy clusters that use Cassandra, Elasticsearch and similar NoSQL technologies to index and process data. We go to quite some lengths to make sure we can consume and process records quickly.

One of our clients has asked us to export their data so they can cross-reference it in SQL Server. It's been quite some time since I used SQL server in anger (2008) so I'm a little out of touch with the art of the possible nowadays.

While the client has data centres and a range of skilled people (DBAs, devs, etc), the department we're dealing with have been given a single server running SQL Server 2014 and have limited technical knowledge. It's a massive organisation with strict regulatory requirements which usually translates into months of paperwork, process and sign-off to get resources allocated.

They've asked us to dump ~730M records into their database and then set up a process to push new data as it arrives. That's fairly simple from our end but I have serious concerns about if they're going to be able to actually use the data.

Record length varies but is on the order of 4k for the information they want.

To make things more interesting, nobody seems to really know what specs the server has. Going on other equipment they use, I'd expect something in the 64GB RAM, RAIDed spinning disks and 6-12 cores.

I've mentioned a couple of times that this might be an issue and only get vague reassurances that SQL Server can handle that much data.

Now... I know SQL Server can handle that much data when partitioned, configured properly, and has a skilled DBA to tweak things, but what's a reasonable amount of data to load into SQL instance without someone who knows what they're doing overseeing the process?

Since getting new equipment/staff allocated their end is going to be a time consuming process and their project has a tight deadline, I'd prefer not to wait until it goes horribly wrong.

I know that nobody can give me a hard and fast rule with such vague information, but at what point should I be concerned? 10M / 100M / 500M / 1B?

Comment: How do they plan to cross-reference 730M records if there are no resources  on their end?

Comment: They're attempting to take output from three separate systems including ours. Records relate to fields on their network and thus have a URI that will be (largely) the same across all three data sets. They want three tables, one from each provider and then to JOIN them together to answer questions. They're planning to do this all in SSMS with a couple of staff who have a passing knowledge of SQL Server/Databases

Comment: `what's a reasonable amount of data to load into SQL instance without someone who knows what they're doing overseeing the process?` None. `at what point should I be concerned?` Right at the start, when some moron decided they'd run a database server and ... wouldn't have to administer it, or use their organization's DBA resources.

Comment: I'd be inclined to think that how they manage/use the data you're dumping to them isn't really your problem. Provide the dump as requested and wipe your hands of it. You don't want to even remotely make them think they can get support from you for this.

Comment: @RyanBolger There's a large part of me that agrees. Problem is, this is a project that has been going on for ages and we've explicitly been asked to work with this department to make things as smooth as possible. There's an extent to how far we can go, but being a small startup, we need to offer good customer service as well as number crunching to keep growing. In this industry, word of mouth counts for a lot. So I'm stuck being asked to do this. I think I'm just going to have to give them a sample dump ASAP and wait for them to realise it won't work before picking up the pieces.

Comment: @Hopeless "None." This is like saying that no one should get behind the wheel of a car unless they have acquired expertise in driving both semi-trailers and Lamborhinis. A lofty and perhaps admirable ideal, but not real-world.

Comment: @mickeyf The phrase used was `someone who knows what they're doing`, not `acquired expertise`. I don't know where you pulled that latter phrase from, but I didn't use it, and that's not the phrase I was responding to.  So, actually, it's like saying that no one should drive a car without [at a minimum] `someone who knows what they're doing overseeing the process`.  Which, also seems like a good idea, and does tend to be one of the legal requirements for a starter driver's license in most places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think I can give you a magic "be worried here" number, where anything under that number is "okay" and anything over that number is "bad."

That said, there are a number of red flags in your question, at least to my point of view:

1. "nobody seems to really know what specs the server has."
2. "They've asked us to dump ~730M records into their database and then set up a process to push new data as it arrives."
3. "the department we're dealing with have been given a single server running SQL Server 2014 and have limited technical knowledge."
4. "It's a massive organisation with strict regulatory requirements which usually translates into months of paperwork, process and sign-off to get resources allocated."
5. "Record length varies"

Okay, SQL Server can absolutely handle that amount of data.  I personally have over 20TB on four servers.

However, SQL Server is a lot like some other Microsoft products, in that if you have a couple of tiny databases that are only lightly used, you can just shove it in the corner and generally be mean to it and it'll perk right along and not bite you (at least, not right away), but scaling out requires more thought and effort.

I'm particularly concerned about whether they're planning on doing proper maintenance on the server.  "Dumping ~730M records into their database" on a regular basis without transaction log backups will quickly consume their disk.

I'm also not comforted by:

> They're attempting to take output from three separate systems
>   including ours. Records relate to fields on their network and thus
>   have a URI that will be (largely) the same across all three data sets.
>   They want three tables, one from each provider and then to JOIN them
>   together to answer questions. They're planning to do this all in SSMS
>   with a couple of staff who have a passing knowledge of SQL
>   Server/Databases

I'm not sure this server will be happy if they decide to run terrible queries against it.  It sounds to me like the data may not be normalized and/or may not contain a good join key.

Last but not least, I've had really unpleasant experiences with "We decided to save money by [letting the user administer his/her own server]/[letting the nice kid in the mail room do it]/[telling them we won't support it but they can do whatever they want]."  It's always ended up being expensive and time-consuming to fix.

Comment: The truly ludicrous thing here is that the client in question is funded by a national government, has multiple sites across the country (including some of the most secure data centres out there). But... The whole thing is one huge bureaucracy, with dozens of different suppliers, groups, business units, etc... We've been contracted by one of those business units who have a ton of data (administered by others) and no way to sanitise / cleanse it. The dept that provided the server will no doubt have had a detailed spec, however, that information has never found its way back to us (or ...

Comment: ... the people we deal with). So, Yeah I wholeheartedly agree there are red flags (that's what prompted the question). Unfortunately, since we're not even dealing with techies, scale issues are just not a consideration for them, despite repeated warnings from us. The irony is that they're paying us a not inconsiderable amount of money to provide a cluster designed for just this sort of task (we regularly deal with billions of records), but our system is designed from the ground up to handle it. Politics in the mix means they want to do their own solution for this step *sigh*

Comment: *:facepalm:*  I'm sorry.  :(

Comment: @basic , it could be worse, they could be demanding that you use ms access instead.

Comment: @JimB I'm really sad that SF won't let me leave a reply of simply "LOL!"  :)

Comment: @KatherineVillyard   don't laugh too hard it "might" be your tax dollars hard at work.

Comment: @JimB Nah, Basic is in the UK and I'm over here in Etlanna.  ;)  Seriously, I was laughing at the Microsoft Access, not his plight.

Comment: Put your concerns and reservations in writing, and in detail, then do your reasonable best. Good luck.

Comment: The bit about the client having DBAs, but them not being consulted about/used for/aware of this new SQL server's also a pretty big red flag to indicate this is going to be a total debacle and a dysfunctional environment... then again, so is the word "government".

Comment: @JimB I've been asked to use Excel for that many records (well, same order of magnitude), which I'm pretty sure is worse than MS Access... as hard as that is for me to say, sometimes, there are worse solutions than MS Access.  Not often, but sometimes.

Comment: @hopelessn00b actually excel isn't bad and handling large datasets.  you can now have a million rows.  in the instance of access I'm thinking of in 2009 it was a solution still using access 97.  I pleaded with them to migrate to SQL (they had licenses, and if not, money was not an issue) .  no their mantra was "access is easier"

Comment: @KatherineVillyard Oh you optimist... Like we Brits never sell anything to the US Gov't :)